# Error when migrated the spring boot app to 2x version

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting error while running the app after changing `spring-boot` version to **2.0.9.Release**

> Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration] -> [Help 1]

Could some one help me resolve this?

Comment: Can you attach the complete stack trace?

Comment: Improved formatting will lead to better readability of your question. Please add some more details about your app. You can paste your pom.xml - that would be more helpful.